# Windows 2008 Server + IIS 7. Sessions not worked

Tags: php, windows, session, iis

I'm newbie in IIS Administration and I have a problem.

1.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'my_test_value';
```

in Google Chrome console I see **PHPSESSID=fg32orkv32m4eb8811bbncvks5**

2.php

```
session_start();
echo '<p>' . session_id() . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . session_save_path() . '</p>'; 
print_r($_SESSION);
```

output:

```
fg32orkv32m4eb8811bbncvks5
C:\Windows\temp
Array ( )
```

There is no file contains "fg32orkv32m4eb8811bbncvks5" in C:\Windows\Temp. Directory is writeable.

Comment: print phpinfo() or check php.ini and see what exactly is session.save_path value or location where session is stored..

Comment: @Dinesh session.save_path C:\Windows\temp
In my question I output session_save_path() too

Comment: lol.. sry I should start reading the question properly.. my bad

Comment: dunno about windows, but on unix-ish boxes, php session files are prefixed with `sess_`.

Comment: @MarcB yeah, I know. There is no file like "%fg32orkv32m4eb8811bbncvks5%" in C:\Windows\Temp

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how the server is set up the "C:\Windows\Temp" Directory might be out of the scope allowed to save files from websites.

**Find the web hosting folder and create a tmp folder**, for example "C:\HostingSpaces\tmp"

Then change the tmp folder security properties to include:  IIS_IUSRS at check the MODIFY option.

Now find your main PHP.ini file with entry "session.save_path = " and in this example you hard code the tmp path to the following:

**session.save_path = "C:\HostingSpaces\tmp"**

Save it. Restart the IIS server and sessions will save correctly.